# Postgresql SQL throws ambiguous column error

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I have the following table in my Postgres database

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."zuffs" 
(
 "hash" bigint NOT NULL,
 "zuff" BIGINT NOT NULL,
 "lat" INTEGER NOT NULL,
 "lng" INTEGER NOT NULL,
 "weather" INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
 "expires" INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
 "clients" INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
 CONSTRAINT "zuffs_hash" PRIMARY KEY ("hash")
) WITH (oids = false);
```

to which I want to add a new row or update the `weather, expires & clients` columns if the row already exists.  To do this I get my PHP script to generate the following SQL

```
INSERT INTO zuffs (hash,zuff,lat,lng,weather,expires)         
VALUES(5523216,14978310951341,4978,589,105906435,4380919) ON CONFLICT(hash) DO UPDATE SET 
weather = 105906435,expires = 4380919,clients = clients + 1;
```

which fails with the error

> ERROR: column reference "clients" is ambiguous

I fail to see why this might be happening.  I hope that someone here can explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the UPDATE part you should use the EXCLUDED "row" to reference the values. And to reference the existing value, you need to prefix the column with the table again to avoid the ambiguity between "excluded" and "current" values:

```
INSERT INTO zuffs (hash,zuff,lat,lng,weather,expires)         
VALUES (5523216,14978310951341,4978,589,105906435,4380919) 
ON CONFLICT(hash) DO UPDATE 
  SET weather = excluded.weather,
      expires = excluded.expires,
      clients = zuffs.clients + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works.  However, it is not at all clear to me what `ÈXCLUDED` means in this context.  The documentation appears ratther dense on this point - or perhaps it is just me.  Should it be interpreted as meaning the row currently in question (i.e identified by the unique Hash value).  Also why is `clients = zuffs.clients + 1` avoiding ambiguity?  Ambiguity implies that I might somehow have been referring to some other clients column and I cannot see how.

Comment: `excluded` refers to the row (values) that was not inserted. The left side of the assignment is in-ambigous. However the right hand side could refer to the excluded value or the current value in the table.